# CSS list menu is not changing background-color

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to create menu from list and on `:hover` event changing background-color. Items in menu that are able to dropdown have a `class .dropdown` and I cannot make them to change background-color on hover event.

This is my HTML code:

```
<nav id="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Company</a></li>
        <li class="selected dropdown"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And this is CSS I made:

```
// no dropdown items
#menubar #menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 1.2em 1.6em 1.2em 1.6em;
    color: grey;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
#menubar #menu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: #36C7E3;
}
// dropdown items
#menubar #menu .dropdown a {
    background:url('http://www.portalworkbook.com.br/static/admin/img/select-caret.png') no-repeat right 25px;
}
#menubar #menu .dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #36C7E3;
    background:url('https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/developer_manual/_images/caret-dark.png') no-repeat right 25px;
}
```

This is [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bimbochobot/6egbn0b7/) with my issue.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Its the background image url causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `background` property overrides `background-color` 
Just add the color before the background url like this:
`background: #36C7E3 url('https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/developer_manual/_images/caret-dark.png') no-repeat right 25px;`

Check the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/heshamElghndour/y2koxx6d/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the full property name for each:

```
#menubar #menu li.dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #36C7E3;
    background-image:url('https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/developer_manual/_images/caret-dark.png') no-repeat right 25px;
}
```

Or, you can use the background shorthand and specify it all in one line:

```
background: #36C7E3 url('https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/developer_manual/_images/caret-dark.png') no-repeat right 25px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You add background image try to remove it then it will work:

```
#menubar #menu .dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you want to use image and color at the same time add the background as

background-image: url('');